# Formula to recognize a column in a table via a cell reference

Tags: excel, formula

I'm using the =AVERAGEIFS function in Excel and am trying to have it recognize that I want to input a column reference.

I have a dropdown table so that if someone wants to find a value in my table, they can automatically see it. In `C11:C14` I have the dropdown values. Everything works except `C14`, which references a column in a table in a different worksheet. I've tried inputting `"Master!Table1[Sum 10%]"` into `C14`, but the formula won't recognize that I am trying to call a column. Any thoughts?

```
 =AVERAGEIFS(C14, Table1[Division],C13, Table1[Product Domain], C12, Table1[Lead Source], C11)
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Is this about the dropdown in C14 or the Averageifs() function?

Comment: is the format of your `AverageIfs` formula correct? (i.e. `AVERAGEIFS(average_range, criteria_range1,criteria1, criteria_range2, criteria2...)`

Comment: This is about both. Yes, my averageifs is correct; if I insert 'Table1[Sum 10%]' in directly to the averageifs function where C14 is located, the formula works. However, if C14 has 'Table1[Sum 10%]' then the formula will not work.

Comment: is it possible Table1[Product Domain] needs to be ['Product Domain']?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Mr.Monshaw. I don't have any issues with the Table1[Product Domain].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that the name scope for Table1 is Workbook and try `INDIRECT(C14)` instead of `C14`.